# API-Platform - Switch to mySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, api-platform.com

I am trying out API-Platform. I installed the latest version and am running it in Docker on Windows 10. The default db is postgres and want to use MySQL.

I installed the default version with postgres and was able to get it up and running.

I changed the docker-compose.yaml

```
db:
  image: mysql:8
  environment: 
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=api
    - MYSQL_USER=api-platform
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
  volumes:
    - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
    - target: 3306
      published: 3306
      protocol: tcp
```

and api/.env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://api-platform:!ChangeMe!@127.0.0.1:3306/api
```

file to use MySQL 8.0. Everything seems to run, but I see in the Docker log

```
php_1 | Waiting for db to be ready...
```

and when I open up the browser to https://127.0.0.1:8443 I get a 502 Bad Gateway.

Any clues to the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your the contents of you `doctrine.yaml` file?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did to get MySQL 8 working in API Platform.

Downloaded the latest version of API Platform 2.5.6

docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: mysql:8
  command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
  restart: always
  security_opt:
    - seccomp:unconfirmed
  enviroment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_USER=api-platform
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=api
  volumes:
    -  db-data:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:
    - target: 3306
      published: 3306
      protocol: tcp
```

\api.env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://api-platform:!ChangeMe!@db:3306/api?server_version=8
```

\api\Dockerfile

```
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .\build-deps \
    $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    icu-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip \
; \
docker-php-ext-configure zip; \
docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
    intl \
    pdo_mysql \
    zip \
; \
```

\api\docker\php\docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#if ls -A src/Migrations/*.php > /dev/null 2>&1; then
#    bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction
#fi
```

Would be nice for the migration scripts to handle MySQL.
At least I have it up and running now.

Comment: is this working with php8 as well? seems to me this
```
libzip-dev \
    pdo_mysql \ <- THIS LINE
    zip \
```
is causing come issue